# Docker bridge -> route over specific interface

Tags: docker

I have two interfaces on the host. Docker is installed and br0 routes over the default interface (eth0) via a linux bridge br-unattrib. I've added a second docker bridge (br-alt), and I want it to route over the secondary link (eth1).

How do I go about ensuring that br-alt pods have their network routed over eth1?

I've got the following (relevant parts of inspect) for my bridge, and the pod I have running still routes over eth0

```
"IPAM": {
    "Driver": "default",
    "Options": {},
    "Config": [
        {
            "Subnet": "172.16.32.0/24",
            "IPRange": "172.16.32.192/26",
            "AuxiliaryAddresses": {
                "hostint": "172.16.32.5",
                "router": "172.16.32.1"
            }
        }
    ]
},
"Internal": false,
"Attachable": false,
"Ingress": false,
"ConfigFrom": {
    "Network": ""
},
"Options": {
    "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "br-unattrib"
```

Comment: com.docker.network.bridge.name = bridge name to be used when creating the Linux bridge and eth1 is not a bridge

Comment: Good catch - in my attempt to simplify, I over simplified my setup :/ I've edited the initial post

Comment: Doing this kind of routing requires policy/source-based routing. It's implemented on Linux with `ip rule` selectors and additional routing tables. I wouldn't know how to integrate this in Docker.

Comment: This is a poor comment - what I'm trying to accomplish here is sort of a baked-in feature if you will of literally all other virtualization software. You spin up a bridge interface, drop containers (LXC) or VMs onto it, and they're a part of that networking (and default host networking isn't in play at all). I understand that Docker relies on IPTables for networking, but how is that so far, it doesn't seem to be possible to specify N number of Docker bridges that are bound to a specific adapter? And thus, the pods in that bridge have networking via their bound adapter? This isn't hard..